# get value from SOAP response in Script Assertion

Tags: groovy, soapui

I try to save attachment from SOAP response using following `Groovy` script as `Script Assertion` in SoapUI.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def props = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
def outputDir = new File(context.expand('${Properties#outputFolder}'))

responseContent = context.response
def parsedXML = new XmlSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
def out_filename = parsedXML.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'name' }.toString();
out_filename = out_filename.substring(1, out_filename.length() - 1);
props.setPropertyValue("out_filename",out_filename);

def fileName = outputDir.toString() +  '\\' + out_filename
def response = messageExchange.response
assert null != response, "response is null"
def outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName))
def ins = messageExchange.responseAttachments[0]?.inputStream

if (ins) {
com.eviware.soapui.support.Tools.writeAll(outFile, ins)
}
ins.close()
outFile.close()
```

It is successfully saved, when I execute it manually, but it fails when SOAP request is executed. Error: `out_filename` is null.

Comment: Executing just the request will not execute a Groovy script step. You can either add the SOAP request as a call to it in the script and just execute the script, or you can execute the test case, which will execute the SOAP request step and the Groovy script step, but make sure the order is right.

Comment: @ou_ryperd : It is defined as Script Assertion, so it is executed when SOAP response is received.